# React-native 0.45 upgrade to 0.52 (Project is made with Ignite-cli)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, redux

I have a fully functional app made with rn: 0.45, now I want to upgrade it to latest rn version but I am unable to upgrade as my app crashes whenever I upgrade, showing no error whatsoever, I am using a react-native-git upgrade.

My project is made with ignite-cli, can anyone suggest the correct steps to upgrade rn as documented steps are not working for me.

Comment: that one such a great jump, have you tried this steps? https://gist.github.com/JonnyBurger/ac07c280dcc19e916409acb82921164c

Comment: @IPutuYogaPermana thanks for your response, I haven't tried this yet, but will surely try this.

Comment: so any solution? I have similar upgrade to do

Comment: @Raheel Hasan, Yes I have upgraded my project manually, dealing with each third party library one by one.